# DDD for a domain having composite relationship

Tags: domain-driven-design

Assume that I have two aggregates e.g. `Document` and `Binder`. A `Document` could be standalone so we have modeled it as an Aggregate and in similar way we modeled Binder also an aggregate. Now the problem is that a `Document` could be inside a `Binder` as well, now how to model this scenario. When a `Document` is inside a `Binder` to work on the `Document` we may have to check some invariant related to `Binder` before allowing the user to work on the `Document`.

One way I could think of is having two model

1. `Document` (an Aggregate)
2. `BoundedDocument` (an Entity inside `Binder` Aggregate)

Is there a better way to model this scenario.

Comment: The word *before* is strange here. Does your Domain have a command like `StartWorkingOnDocument`? Or `PerformSomeChangesToTheDocument`?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu It is just a generic term, even editing a `Document` can be allowed only if it satisfy the invariant of the `Binder` and of the `Document`

Comment: But how does your Domain know that somebody started to work on a document? Before persisting changes

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu the `Document` I talk about is a structured document, so it will have methods for updating data, but before updating  certain invariant has to be met

Comment: So, you need to check the invariant after the user have filled the data in the UI and pressed the SAVE button but before the changes are persisted?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu yes

Comment: But from your question I understand that you need to check the invariant *before* the user is allowed to fill any data in the UI, i.e. the UI blocks the user when some invariants are not met.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172371/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-wolverine).

Comment: @wolverine aggregate design depends on so many things such as transactional load of your system, exact nature of these invariants, etc. With the little information you provided, it's almost impossible to answer. Domain modelling is about tradeoffs that require knowing all the ins and outs of the business case - and validation of these tradeoffs by a domain expert is also very important.

Comment: @guillaume31 I agree with what you said, I also know that, I have asked this question not in the hope that I will get exact solution, but to see whether I get any other direction which I have missed

Comment: But ask it to 10 people using DDD and you'll get 10 different accounts of how they do something they think is vaguely similar in their systems. I'm not sure asking for inspiration is a good way to solve your problem (besides being arguably outside StackOverflow's guidelines).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you should have two separate Aggregates, `Document` and `Binder`, and use a Saga (Process manager) to eventually bring the entire system in a valid state. In other words, you should model the modification of a binded document as a business process.

This Saga would be started with all the informations regarding the modification of the document (i.e. all the modified properties in the document) then it would send a command to the Binder that would check its own invariant and if all is OK then it would send the update command to the Document aggregate. It should also react to all the events that could bring the system to an invalid state, i.e. events generated by the Binder Aggregate because there is the possibility that the documents in the binder enter in an invalid state because of the Binder Aggregate mutation.

A different architecture would be to send the update command directly to the Document Aggregate, without checking the invariant. Then, the Saga would react to the document update events by sending a command to the Binder Aggregate. If the Binder says that it is not OK then the Saga would send compensating commands to the binded Document. This design would be more permissive with invalid documents but it is simpler.

Both the designs would eventually bring the system in a valid state but the first would minimize the times that an invalid document exists at the cost of increased complexity because the Saga would need to be started and would store the document modification information.

The alternative is that you create a new nested-entity inside the Binder Aggregate, namely the `BindedDocument` but this entity doesn't seem to be conceptually different from the Document Aggregate. This is reflected by the code duplication that you would have.